# How can Bing Speech to Text API support adding punctuations on generated text?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I'm using Bing Speech to Text API (https://speech.platform.bing.com/recognize POST method) to transform voice to text, but returned JSON result doesn't contain punctuations, how can I get punctuated result? Thanks!

Like below, it doesn't contain any punctuation within the transformed text:

> Each one of us had some good porn in public with no you don't mind but we could get by there in some areas of our personal time Skype get about her attitude can be converted into a practical realities You think I'll talk

Return JSON example:

> {"version":"3.0","header":{"status":"success","scenario":"smd","name":"Each one of us had some good porn in public with no you don't mind but we could get by there in some areas of our personal time Skype get about her attitude can be converted into a practical realities You think I'll talk.","lexical":"each one of us had some good porn in public with no you don't mind but we could get by there in some areas of our personal time skype get about her attitude can be converted into a practical realities you think i'll talk","properties":{"requestid":"92ceb518-b3da-43b9-b6be-1e9244132154","HIGHCONF":"1"}},"results":[{"scenario":"smd","name":"Each one of us had some good porn in public with no you don't mind but we could get by there in some areas of our personal time Skype get about her attitude can be converted into a practical realities You think I'll talk.","lexical":"each one of us had some good porn in public with no you don't mind but we could get by there in some areas of our personal time skype get about her attitude can be converted into a practical realities you think i'll talk","confidence":"0.857573","properties":{"HIGHCONF":"1"}}]}

Answer (score 0):

Currently the punctuation functionality is not turned on. It will be rolled out in the next month.

Bing Speech

Comment: Do you have a reference or source for this information?